# How to get elm time subscriptions x times per seconds

Tags: elm

In the elm-guide there is a section in Effects/Time which gives an example to return a subscription `Time.every second`.

In the documentation there seems to be only the granularity units `millisecond`, `second`, `minute`, etc...

Is there a way to get a subscription like 20 per second or another subgranularity?

What is the best way to achieve something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Time` is just an alias for `Float`, so you can do numeric operations on it. If you want a subscription to fire 20 times a second, just make sure it fires every `1/20` of a second.

In other words: `Time.every (second / 20.0)`